# HQL query and SELECT N+1 issue when using IN

Tags: sql, hibernate, hql

I have some "SELECT n+1" issues with an HSQL query using Hibernate and Spring Data using the IN clause.

We have some organizations that published applications thought a PublishedApplication object.
The current model is (and it cannot be changed easily):

```
public class Application {
    Organization organization;
    ...
}

public class Organization {
    ...
}


public class PublishedApplication extends ... {

    @OneToOne(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, orphanRemoval = true)
    private Application application;

    @ManyToOne(cascade = CascadeType.REFRESH)
    @JoinColumn(name="publishingorganization_uuid")
    protected Organization publishingOrganization;
}
```

I want to list all apps that are published by one of my organizations.

So I'v write this query:

```
@Query(value = "SELECT DISTINCT p.application 
                FROM PublishedApplication p 
                WHERE p.publishingOrganization IN ?1")
 List<Application> findAllByPublishedOrganizationIn(List<Organization> organizations);
```

This works well but when I enable SQL log, I see:

- 1 SELECT to get "publishedapplication.application": ok it's the main request.
- 3 SELECT to get "organization": I have access to 10 organizations but only 3 have published an application

Here is the code call:

```
log.debug("Before");
List<Application> applications = applicationRepository.findAllByPublishedOrganizationIn(organizations);
log.debug("After");
```

And here is the Log:

```
ApplicationService       : Before

Hibernate: select distinct applicatio1_.uuid as uuid1_0_, applicatio1_.version as version2_0_, applicatio1_.description as descript3_0_, applicatio1_.lastversiondate as lastvers4_0_, applicatio1_.name as name5_0_, applicatio1_.organization_uuid as organiza6_0_ from publishedapplication publisheda0_ inner join applications applicatio1_ on publisheda0_.application_uuid=applicatio1_.uuid where publisheda0_.publishingorganization_uuid in (? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ? , ?)
Hibernate: select organizati0_.uuid as uuid1_8_0_, organizati0_.version as version2_8_0_, organizati0_.description as descript3_8_0_, organizati0_.name as name4_8_0_ from organizations organizati0_ where organizati0_.uuid=?
Hibernate: select organizati0_.uuid as uuid1_8_0_, organizati0_.version as version2_8_0_, organizati0_.description as descript3_8_0_, organizati0_.name as name4_8_0_ from organizations organizati0_ where organizati0_.uuid=?
Hibernate: select organizati0_.uuid as uuid1_8_0_, organizati0_.version as version2_8_0_, organizati0_.description as descript3_8_0_, organizati0_.name as name4_8_0_ from organizations organizati0_ where organizati0_.uuid=?

ApplicationService       : After
```

I suppose that the 3 'SELECT organization' are triggered by doing this "p.publishingOrganization IN".
Is it a way to resolve this problem using a single SELECT?
Something like this in SQL:

```
List<Organization> orgs = ...
List<String> orgsIds = ...
doSQL("SELECT * 
       FROM publishedApplication p 
       WHERE p.publishingOrganizationId IN (" + orgsIds.join(",") + ")");
```

Thanks

EDIT: I resolve this using:

```
SELECT DISTINCT p.application FROM PublishedApplication p JOIN FETCH p.application.organization WHERE p.publishingOrganization IN ?1
```

Comment: In the N+1 select issue, the N+1 select are sent to the database after the main query. From what you describe, you seems to get the N+1 select before. In addition, to call `findAllByPublishedOrganizationIn`, you need to pass an `Organization` list... Are you sure that the N+1 queries on `Organization` are not the result of what you do before calling `findAllByPublishedOrganizationIn` ? Could you show the code doing this ?

Comment: You can easily check the generated SQL queries by logging them. I don't think you are searching at the right place.

Comment: @Thierry I've updated my post (Made a mistkae in the request order, the main query is made before the N queries). All request are made between "Before" and "After" log message.

Comment: Thanks. One last question : what do you want to do ? Not issue the 3 select because you do not need this data, or do you want to load Application and Organization all in one query ?

Comment: Your last comment put me on the right way. An application has a link to Organization too. Its this proprty that trigger the SELECT.
I dindn't look for that because, I though that Hibernate will use Application.setOrganization(...) to load the organization of an application.
So I simply need to FETCH `p.application.organization`
`SELECT DISTINCT p.application FROM PublishedApplication p JOIN FETCH p.application.organization WHERE p.publishingOrganization IN ?1`